# Mongoose's populate method breaks promise chain?

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

So I have a mongoose Schema that looks like this:

```js
var Functionary = new Schema({
  person: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Person'
  },
  dateOfAssignment: Date,
  dateOfDischarge: Date,
  isActive: Boolean
});

var PositionSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  maxHeadCount: Number,
  minHeadCount: Number,
  currentHeadCount: Number,
  currentlyHolding: [Functionary],
  historical: [Functionary],
  responsibleTo: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Position'
  }
});
```

*note that the Position document can reference itself in the `ResponsibleTo` field.

Now, I'm trying to build a method that will search the `Positions` collection, populate the `currentlyHolding[].person.name field` and the `responsibleTo.currentlyHolding[].person.name` field, and also return the total number of records found (for paging purposes on the front-end).

Here's what my code looks like:

```js
exports.search = function(req, res) {
  var result = {
    records: null,
    count: 0,
    currentPage: req.params.page,
    totalPages: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
    execTime: 0
  };

  var startTime = new Date();

  var populateQuery = [
    {
      path: 'currentlyHolding.person',
      select: 'name'
    }, {
      path:'responsibleTo',
      select:'name currentlyHolding.person'
    }
  ];

  Position.find(
    {
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: '.*' + req.params.keyword + '.*', $options: 'i' } },
        { description: { $regex: '.*' + req.params.keyword + '.*', $options: 'i' } }
      ]
    },
    {},
    {
      skip: (result.currentPage - 1) * result.pageSize,
      limit: result.pageSize,
      sort: 'name'
    })
  .exec()
  .populate(populateQuery)
  .then(function(doc) {
    result.records = doc;
  });

  Position.count(
    {
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: '.*' + req.params.keyword + '.*', $options: 'i' } },
        { description: { $regex: '.*' + req.params.keyword + '.*', $options: 'i' } }
      ]
    })
  .exec()
  .then(function(doc) {
    result.count = doc;
    result.totalPages = Math.ceil(result.count / result.pageSize);
  })
  .then(function() {
    var endTime = new Date();
    result.execTime = endTime - startTime;
    return res.json(200, result);
  });
};
```

My problem is when I run the first query with the populate method (as is shown), it doesn't work. I take away the populate and it works. Is it true that the populate method will break the promise? If so, are there better ways to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked, but this might still help others so here we go:

[According to the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate), `.populate()` doesn't return a promise. For that to happen you should chain `.execPopulate()`.

Alternatively, you can put `.populate()` before `.exec()`. The latter will terminate the query builder interface and return a promise for you.